# How do I add Javascript to pages using Core functions?

Tags: hooks

I'm calling this from a hook but it's not working.  Am I doing something wrong?

CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScript("alert('hello');");

I confirmed that it's running by adding debug code to addScript.

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Are you sure your hook is being called?

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming that I'm doing it correctly.  When I get a chance, I'll try to debug core and figure out why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you gave is correct. I suggest you:

1. Ensure your code is actually running (add a debug statement or `exit();` in your code).
2. Clear your caches. If your page is being cached by the cms then that might be why you're not seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Coleman, but I'm still having the problem.